# Web link em TextView sem mostrar url, tipo "Clique aqui"

Tags: android, link, textview

O objetivo é criar um diálogo com alguns links para websites.

O código a seguir já faz isso, mas os URL aparecem explicitas (www....) e eu gostaria que fossem 'escondidas' atrás de palavras como 'clique aqui'.

```
public void show() {
    PackageInfo versionInfo = getPackageInfo();

    String EULA_PREFIX = "eula_";
    final SpannableString how = new SpannableString(mActivity.getString(R.string.url_how));
    final SpannableString privacy = new SpannableString(mActivity.getString(R.string.url_privacy));
    final SpannableString terms = new SpannableString(mActivity.getString(R.string.url_terms));
    final String eulaKey = EULA_PREFIX + versionInfo.versionCode;
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
    boolean hasBeenShown = prefs.getBoolean(eulaKey, false);
    TextView textView = new TextView(mActivity);

    textView.setText(mActivity.getString(R.string.eula_updates) + "\n\n"
            + mActivity.getString(R.string.str_how) + how + "\n\n"
            + mActivity.getString(R.string.str_privacy) + privacy + "\n\n"
            + mActivity.getString(R.string.str_terms) + terms + "\n\n"
            + mActivity.getString(R.string.str_agree)
    );

    textView.setAutoLinkMask(RESULT_OK);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

    String title = mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name) + " v" + versionInfo.versionName;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setView(textView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_agree, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {                       
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
                    editor.apply();
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_disagree, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                        
                    mActivity.finish();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();        
}
```

Pra deixar mais claro, se fosse HTML, obteria este efeito assim:

```
<a href="www.exemplo.com">clique aqui</a>
```

De forma que o link funciona, mas o que o usuário vê e toca é a expressão 'clique aqui'

Trecho de `string.xml`

```
        <string name="eula_updates">Updates in this version: Test version. Updates and bugs.</string>
<string name="url_how">https://www.exemplo.com/index.html#header3-2</string>
<string name="url_privacy">https://www.exemplo.com/index.html#header3-6</string>
<string name="url_terms">https://www.exemplo.com.br/index.html#content5-9</string>
<string name="str_how">How to use MOTONOIX </string>
<string name="str_privacy">MOTONOIX privacy policy  </string>
<string name="str_terms">MOTONOIX Terms of Use here </string>
<string name="str_agree">By clicking the button to continue, you declare that you are in compliance with this policy and the terms presented</string>
```

Tem como fazer isso no Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a dica do ramaral, o código ficou assim:

```
 public void show() {
    PackageInfo versionInfo = getPackageInfo();
    String EULA_PREFIX = "eula_";        
    final String eulaKey = EULA_PREFIX + versionInfo.versionCode;
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
    boolean hasBeenShown = prefs.getBoolean(eulaKey, false);
    if (!hasBeenShown) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(mActivity);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mActivity.getString(R.string.eula_updates) + "\n\n"
                + mActivity.getString(R.string.str_how) + mActivity.getString(R.string.url_how) + "\n\n"
                + mActivity.getString(R.string.str_privacy) + mActivity.getString(R.string.url_privacy) + "\n\n"
                + mActivity.getString(R.string.str_terms) + mActivity.getString(R.string.url_terms) + "\n\n"
                + mActivity.getString(R.string.str_agree))
        );
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        String title = mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name) + " v" + versionInfo.versionName;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setView(textView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_agree, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        // Mark this version as read.
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
                        editor.apply();

                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_disagree, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Close the activity as they have declined the EULA
                        mActivity.finish();
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

E o `string.xml`:

```
<string name="eula_updates">Updates in this version: Test version. Updates and bugs.</string>
<string name="url_how">&lt;a href="https://www.exemplo.com/index.html#header3-2">touch here&lt;/a>&lt;/p></string>
<string name="url_privacy">&lt;a href="https://www.exemplo.com/index.html#header3-6">touch here&lt;/a>&lt;/p></string>
<string name="url_terms">&lt;a href="https://www.exemplo.com/index.html#content5-9">touch here&lt;/a>&lt;/p></string>
<string name="str_how">&lt;p>"How to use MOTONOIX "</string>
<string name="str_privacy">&lt;p>"MOTONOIX privacy policy "</string>
<string name="str_terms">&lt;p>"MOTONOIX Terms of Use "</string>
<string name="str_agree">&lt;p>"By clicking the button to continue, you declare that you are in compliance with this policy and the terms presented.&lt;/p></string>
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma das formas possíveis é declarar um *resource string* desta forma:

```
<string name="link_example">&lt;a href="http://www.exemplo.com">Clique aqui&lt;/a></string>
```

e usá-lo assim no java

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.link_example)));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Ao construir o HTML deve:

- incluir http:// no link.
- usar `&lt;` em vez de `<`

Comment: foi a sua dica que me deu a resposta, mas como são vários links e textos, resolvi adicionar uma resposta com o código modificado, incluindo o `strings.xml` que também acrescentei à pergunta para se comparar as versões. Obrigado mais uma vez. Vc é fera!